# Extent report is not giving proper report on parallel execution

Tags: selenium-grid, extentreports

ReporterClass.Java:

```
package POM_Classes;

import com.aventstack.extentreports.AnalysisStrategy;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.reporter.ExtentHtmlReporter;

public class ReporterClass {

    public static ExtentHtmlReporter html;
    public ExtentReports extent;
    public ExtentTest test, suiteTest;
    public String testCaseName, testNodes, testDescription, category, authors;

    public void startResult() {
        html = new ExtentHtmlReporter("./reports/result.html");
        html.setAppendExisting(true);
        extent = new ExtentReports();

        extent.attachReporter(html);        
    }

    /*public ExtentTest startTestModule(String testCaseName, String testDescription) {
        suiteTest = extent.createTest(testCaseName, testDescription);
        return suiteTest;
    }*/

    public ExtentTest startTestCase(String testName) {
        System.out.println(testName);
        test = extent.createTest(testName);
        return test;
    }

    public void reportStep(String desc, String status) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {
            test.pass(desc);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {
            test.fail(desc);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("WARNING")) {
            test.warning(desc);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("INFO")) {
            test.info(desc);
        }
    }

    public void endTestcase() {
        extent.setAnalysisStrategy(AnalysisStrategy.CLASS);
    }

    public void endResult() {
        extent.flush();
    }

}
```

Usage:

```
@Test   
    public void 961_NavigateToMyAlertsAndAddNewAlerts()
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, ATUTestRecorderException, APIException {

        driver = launchTargetUrl(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString());
        startResult();
        test = startTestCase(Thread.currentThread().getStackTrace()[1].getMethodName().toString()); 
        LoginApplication(driver,transactionusername, transactionuserpassword,test);
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver,test);
        homePage.MyAlerts.click();
        MyAlerts myalerts = new MyAlerts(driver,test);
        String selectedcardName;
        selectedcardName = driver.findElement(myalerts.cardName).getText().trim();
        System.out.println(selectedcardName);       
    }



    @AfterMethod
    public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) throws ATUTestRecorderException {   
        resultOfTest(result);
        endTestcase();
        endResult();
        closeBrowsers(driver);
    }
```

The test case which first gets completed has the report and if the another test case is completed then that result overrides the old one..

If I change public static ExtentReports extent; then it maintains only thread so it logs only one test case and the other parallel execution is not even recorded.. How to resolve this?

Comment: I would suggest understanding parallelism first.  None of your methods are synchronized, your tests overlap each other due to shared variables and the Extent instance is been created multiple times. There are many examples available how to do this, and you can start with the docs.

Comment: Is this possible in extent report?

Comment: It is possible.

Comment: I've done it using thread local treating the my own report wrapper class much like I do webdrivers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, here you go. I haven't tested this yet, but this should allow you to use Extent with parallel usage.

Reporter:

```
public abstract class ReporterClass {

    private static final ExtentReports EXTENT = ExtentManager.getInstance();

    public ExtentTest test, suiteTest;
    public String testCaseName, testNodes, testDescription, category, authors;

    public synchronized ExtentTest startTestCase(String testName) {
        System.out.println(testName);
        return ExtentTestManager.createTest(testName);
    }

    public synchronized void reportStep(String desc, String status) {
        if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("PASS")) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().pass(desc);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("FAIL")) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().fail(desc);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("WARNING")) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().warning(desc);
        } else if (status.equalsIgnoreCase("INFO")) {
            ExtentTestManager.getTest().info(desc);
        }
    }

    public synchronized void endResult() {
        EXTENT.flush();
    }

    @BeforeMethod
    public synchronized void beforeMethod(Method method) {
        startTestCase(method.getName());
    }

    @AfterMethod
    public synchronized void afterMethod(ITestResult result) throws ATUTestRecorderException {   
        reportStep(result.getThrowable(), result.getStatus());
        endResult();
        closeBrowsers(driver);
    }

}
```

Base:

```
public abstract class BaseClass extends ReporterClass {

    // .. abstractions

}
```

Extent utils:

```
public class ExtentTestManager {

    static Map<Integer, ExtentTest> extentTestMap = new HashMap<Integer, ExtentTest>();
    private static final ExtentReports EXTENT = ExtentManager.getInstance();

    public static synchronized ExtentTest getTest() {
        return extentTestMap.get((int) (long) (Thread.currentThread().getId()));
    }

    public static synchronized ExtentTest createTest(String testName) {
        return createTest(testName, "");
    }

    public static synchronized ExtentTest createTest(String testName, String desc) {
        ExtentTest test = EXTENT.createTest(testName, desc);
        extentTestMap.put((int) (long) (Thread.currentThread().getId()), test);

        return test;
    }

}


public class ExtentManager {

    private static ExtentReports extent;

    public synchronized static ExtentReports getInstance() {
        if (extent == null) {
            createInstance("reports/extent.html");
        }

        return extent;
    }

    public synchronized static ExtentReports createInstance(String fileName) {
        ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.BOTTOM);
        htmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(true);
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle(fileName);
        htmlReporter.config().setEncoding("utf-8");
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName(fileName);
        htmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);

        extent = new ExtentReports();
        extent.setAnalysisStrategy(AnalysisStrategy.CLASS);
        extent.attachReporter(htmlReporter);

        return extent;
    }

}
```

Finally, your slim tests. Notice there is 0 lines of reporter code here - see ReporterClass.

```
public class MyTestsClass extends BaseClass {
    @Test   
    public void 961_NavigateToMyAlertsAndAddNewAlerts()
            throws IOException, InterruptedException, ATUTestRecorderException, APIException {
        driver = launchTargetUrl(this.getClass().getSimpleName().toString());
        LoginApplication(driver,transactionusername, transactionuserpassword,test);
        HomePage homePage = new HomePage(driver,test);
        homePage.MyAlerts.click();
        MyAlerts myalerts = new MyAlerts(driver,test);
        String selectedcardName;
        selectedcardName = driver.findElement(myalerts.cardName).getText().trim();
        System.out.println(selectedcardName);       
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. I am checking now

Comment: Illegal modifier for the field extent; only public, protected, private, static, final, transient & volatile are permitted  for the below line                                                                     private synchronized static ExtentReports extent;

Comment: Consider 3 test cases runs in parallel. some of the screenshot missing 1st and 2nd test case which is getting finished.. The test finishes last (3rd) test case has 1st and 2nd test case screenshots as well..

Comment: This is why I run them as separate reports in my framework.  I did not want to use unique names for the screenshots, they were named based upon the steps, but would be the same for different browsers, so each browser has its own report and corresponding screenshots.

Comment: @ChanGan please share your updated code.  PS.  as Bill said, if your screenshot names are not unique, that is the preferred way.

Answer (score 1):

```
//Add below class in your Project. First you need to add the respective object and 
//call them respectively. Declaring Extent and Driver as static is a big problem in 
//Parallel/execution.
//Avoid using static as far as possible by using the below class.

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentReports;
import com.aventstack.extentreports.ExtentTest;

public class WebDriverFactory {

private static ThreadLocal<WebDriver> drivers=new ThreadLocal<>();
private static List<WebDriver> storeDrivers=new ArrayList<WebDriver>();
private static List<ExtentTest> extent=new ArrayList<ExtentTest>();
private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> reports=new ThreadLocal<ExtentTest>();

static 
{
    Runtime.getRuntime().addShutdownHook(new Thread(){
        public void run()
        {
            storeDrivers.stream().forEach(WebDriver::quit);
        }
    });
 }


public static WebDriver getDriver() 
{
 return drivers.get();
 }
 public static ExtentTest getextentReportObject()   
 {
   return reports.get();
 }

 public static void addDriver(WebDriver driver) 
 {

    storeDrivers.add(driver);
   drivers.set(driver);
 }

 public static void addExtentReportObject(ExtentTest report)    
 {

   extent.add(report);
   reports.set(report);
  }

  public static void removeDriver()
 {
  storeDrivers.remove(drivers.get());
  drivers.remove();

  }
  }
//Add and Invoke the object in the following way


  /*** Add and invoke the object in the below fashion **/

    WebDriverFactory.addExtentReportObject(extent.createTest("Monitor Scenario 
   ").createNode("Monitor Page Validation"));
   WebDriverFactory.getextentReportObject().assignCategory("@SmokeTest");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. foursyth solution worked for me..