# Extent Report Issue Parallel testing

Tags: android, java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, automation

I have the following Reporting code:

```
public class Reporting {
    private ExtentHtmlReporter extentHtmlReporter;

    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentReports> extentReports = new ThreadLocal<>();
    private static ThreadLocal<ExtentTest> extentTest = new ThreadLocal<>();

    public synchronized ExtentTest createInstanceReport(String testCaseName) {
        System.out.println(extentReports.get());

        new File(Constants.userDir + "/Reports/").mkdirs();

        // To generate report with name
        extentHtmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(
                Constants.userDir + "/Reports/" +
                        "ExecutionReport_" + new SimpleDateFormat(
                        Constants.date).format(new Date()) + ".html");

        // Setting Document Title
        extentHtmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Demo");
        // Setting Report Name
        extentHtmlReporter.config().setReportName("Demo Automation");
        // Setting Theme
        extentHtmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.STANDARD);
        // Setting Chart location
        extentHtmlReporter.config().setTestViewChartLocation(ChartLocation.TOP);
        // Setting Chart visibility
        extentHtmlReporter.config().setChartVisibilityOnOpen(false);
        // Setting Time stamp
        extentHtmlReporter.config().setTimeStampFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
        // Setting append exist as true
        extentHtmlReporter.setAppendExisting(true);
        ExtentReports extentReports = new ExtentReports();
        extentReports.attachReporter(extentHtmlReporter);

        // Setting system info
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Name",
                BaseTest.prop.getProperty(Constants.testerName));
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Environment",
                BaseTest.prop.getProperty(Constants.environment));
        extentReports.setSystemInfo("Browser",
                BaseTest.prop.getProperty(Constants.browser));
        Reporting.extentReports.set(extentReports); // Instead of using here extentReport thread like this, Can anyone suggest to use it directly

        // Add test case name in report
        ExtentTest extentTest = Reporting.extentTest.get();
        extentTest = Reporting.extentReports.get().createTest(testCaseName);
        Reporting.extentTest.set(extentTest);

        // Assigning categories
        extentTest.assignCategory(MultiFunction.getProp()
                .getProperty(Constants.browser));

        System.out.println(Reporting.extentReports.get());
        System.out.println(Reporting.extentTest.get());

        return extentTest;
    }

    public synchronized ExtentTest getExtentTest() {
        return extentTest.get();
    }

    public synchronized ExtentReports getInstanceReport() {
        return extentReports.get();
    }

    public synchronized void remove() {
        extentReports.remove();
        extentTest.remove();
    }
}
```

I was trying parallel testing using TestNG (and will have to use Selenium grid and sauce in future). I ***execute 2 test cases*** then ***only one test*** case result is added in the report.

I have isolated the `extentTest`, `extentReporter` and **WebDriver** instances using threadPool.

Tried below with `extentHtmlReporter` instance:

```
1) Tried to make it static(no luck)  
2) Tried to make it local (the same behaviour, getting only 1 test case result)
3) Tried as a non-static global variable ( no luck)
```

***Could you suggest how to solve the above issue?***

Please note:  Only one report is generated. But when I tried to run parallel test cases in debug mode reports are generated for both the test case. I think because one test case gets over its killing some instance (when running in non-debug mode)

Also, I want to redesign the following place in my code:

For `extentRpeort`, I am using:

> Reporting.extentReports.set(extentReports);

To add `extentReport` instance to my `extentReport` Thread.
Instead of adding like this I want to use it directly so as to reduce line of code.

Comment: is two different reports gets generated ?

Comment: no only one report. But when I tried to run parallel testcases in debug mode reports are generated for both the test case

Comment: when you calls method createInstanceReport()

Comment: try to isolate .createTest(testCaseName) method too.

Comment: in BeforeMethod.I tried calling in BeforeSuite but it not even generating report

Comment: @AshishKamble: I didnt get u, Can u explain me what to add to isolate the method

Comment: @Infern0 given a link thats what i was trying to say you dont put put everything in single class.Make different function in different class

Comment: can you debug your code put debug point on .createTest(testCaseName) method, This needs to be get called twice.

Comment: @AshishKamble: Yes I ran in debug mode and the method is called twice. In debug mode for multi threading code works fine but not in normal execution

Comment: @PrashantJeetSingh Please format your code before posting! It is difficult to read it. Also, consider how to use highlights for your question. It helps people to read and understand your problem faster.

Comment: thanks a lot nazar

Comment: Its not clear if you have found a solution, but if not, please check here as well:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759135/extent-report-is-not-giving-proper-report-on-parallel-execution/52770851.  You may have to modify this a little bit to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was with the flushing of extent report instance.
I was using ThreadLocal for storing extent report instance and was flushing the wrong instance.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly you have to generate Report from all executed **TestNG** cases.

However, from code which you shared, it is very visible that you will have some trouble with it. You are making a few critical mistakes and result are obvious:

- For generating reports with **TestNG** I will suggest grabbing information about test execution from ***TestNG listener***. Something like:

  ```
  public final class TestNGListener extends TestListenerAdapter implements IInvokedMethodListener, ISuiteListener {

  @Override
  public void onStart(ITestContext context) {
      Logger.info(buildMessage(Logger.PREFIX_TEST_STARTED, context.getName()));
  }

  @Override
  public void onFinish(ITestContext context) {
      Logger.info(buildMessage(Logger.PREFIX_TEST_FINISHED, context.getName()));
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestStart(ITestResult result) {
      Logger.info(buildMessage(Logger.PREFIX_METHOD_STARTED, getMethodName(result)));
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestSuccess(ITestResult result) {
      Logger.info(buildMessage(Logger.PREFIX_METHOD_SUCCESS, getMethodName(result)));
      processTestResult(result);
  }

  @Override
  public void onTestFailure(ITestResult result) {
      Logger.info(buildMessage(Logger.PREFIX_METHOD_FAILED, getMethodName(result)));
  }
  ```
- You can't do everything in one method! You broke [Single Responsibility Principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle). Your `createInstanceReport()` is doing all jobs (setting report details, set system info, attach an executed test case to report) at one place. You have to redesign this logic to some logical separate operations. After redesigning your problem with the next line:

> Reporting.extentReports.set(extentReports)

Could successfully disappear.

- You have to consider a case, why you need to use exactly `Extent, Reports Version 3`. ***TestNG*** has test reports from the box. They are poor but they are presented out of the box. If you want just to improve it a little bit you could use [ReportNG](https://reportng.uncommons.org/) over TestNG.

It is quite easy to configure: [Configuring ReportNG with TestNG for HTML Reports](https://www.seleniumeasy.com/testng-tutorials/configuring-reportng-with-testng-to-generate-html-reports).

It isn't maintained, but it makes TestNG reports really eye candy and understandable.

Anyway, my suggestion is to use `TestNGListener` for getting info about test cases execution. And read more about good programming practice.

Answer (score 1):

Work with TestNG/jUnit (or other runner framework that you are using) listener, here is a good example how to do it.
Do not put everything in a single class.

https://www.swtestacademy.com/extent-reports-version-3-reporting-testng/

Comment: hey infern0,Actually i want all the reporting code and logic in one class and if you see the code I have only one method for everything, rest 2 methods are just for fetching the instance

Comment: you don't have to create instance each time, just add a new test to it. there is no point everything to be in a single class.

Comment: So thats why i am afraid its going to make two different directories. You need to put if condidtion is directory exist or not before creating a new File.