# Getting NPE when trying to get extent reports for parallel test execution

Tags: java, selenium, parallel-processing, testng, extentreports

I am trying to run a Selenium(Java) test script(which has two 2 @Test methods in it)in parallel - on Chrome browser and on Firefox browser.Once the runs are over I am trying to get an Extent report with the execution summary.

What I observe on screen is - First,Chrome gets launched and the test url gets launched and we are at the login page of the application.At around this time,the Firefox browser gets launched as well and the Chrome browser no longer proceeds with any execution.The Firefox browser completes the execution for the first @Test method,closes the browser and then launches a new firefox browser and finishes off the execution of the second @Test method as well. Chrome on the other hand shows no activity.

When I check the Results I see the following error(s)-

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at testscriptspackage.TestLoginPageFeatures.InvalidCredentials(TestLoginPageFeatures.java:87)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:124)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:580)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:716)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:988)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:125)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:109)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:648)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:505)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:455)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.access$000(SuiteRunner.java:40)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner$SuiteWorker.run(SuiteRunner.java:489)
    at org.testng.internal.thread.ThreadUtil$1.call(ThreadUtil.java:52)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

I went through [Extent Report Issue Parallel testing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52811017/extent-report-issue-parallel-testing) ,[Extent report is not giving proper report on parallel execution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52759135/extent-report-is-not-giving-proper-report-on-parallel-execution?noredirect=1&lq=1) and a few other similar threads but didn't understand much.

Did notice that if instead of @BeforeSuite,I use @BeforeClass then the Chrome as well as Firefox execution happens properly but the problem then is that I only get the results for the Firefox run in my report as a new report is getting created overwriting the earlier one generated for Chrome.I believe it's an issue with Threads so am reading up on the topic.Still since the execution works with @BeforeClass,I am not very sure if I am looking in the right direction..

I have 4 files - 
1.DriverSetup.java - where I am instantiating WebDriver object.
2.GuruLoginPage.java - A page file for the methods and UI elements of the login page.

3. TestLoginPageFeatures.java - Test code

```
  protected GuruLoginPage glp;
  public ExtentHtmlReporter htmlReporter;
  public ExtentReports report;
  public ExtentTest logger;


   @BeforeSuite
    public void  setExtent()
    {
    htmlReporter = new ExtentHtmlReporter(System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/test-output/TestReport.html"); 
    htmlReporter.config().setDocumentTitle("Test Execution Summary"); 
        htmlReporter.config().setReportName("Test Execution Report "); 
        htmlReporter.config().setTheme(Theme.DARK); 


        report = new ExtentReports();  
        report.attachReporter(htmlReporter);
        report.setSystemInfo("User Name", "Ahaan");

    }
       ...
   @Parameters("Browser")
   @BeforeMethod
    public void setup(String br)
     {
     DriverSetup tdriver=new DriverSetup();
     driver=tdriver.LaunchURL(br);
     glp=new GuruLoginPage(driver);
     glp.verifyHomePageLogo();
   }
   ...
  @AfterMethod
  public void getResult(ITestResult result) throws Exception
   {
     .....
    driver.quit();
   }
  ...
  @AfterSuite
  public void endReport()
  {
      report.flush();
  }
```

4. TestNG.xml -

```
<suite name="My Test Suite" parallel="tests" thread-count="2">
    <test name="Guru Bank Tests - Chrome">
     <parameter name="Browser" value="chrome"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="testscriptspackage.TestLoginPageFeatures"/>            
        </classes>
    </test>
    <test name="Guru Bank Tests - Firefox">
     <parameter name="Browser" value="firefox"/>
        <classes>
            <class name="testscriptspackage.TestLoginPageFeatures"/>            
        </classes>
    </test>
</suite>
```

Appreciate any suggestions on what I need to change to get it to work?
Also,can we append data in the Extent report in version 4 of Extent Report?Can't find any code sample for that.Lastly,I am new to Selenium so any other suggestions on the code organisation is appreciated as well.
Thanks.

Comment: It seems like you need to set your ExtentReport logic from Suite level to test level as per your current code, also if by data you mean screenshots of failure or other files so you can append it.

Comment: I'll point you in the right direction, but I'm not going to hand-hold you through the entire process as it's rather complex, but research ThreadLocal.  You should declare both your webdriver AND your extent object as that type to successfully run in parallel, but it's more than just that, but that should be enough to get you started.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions.I will read up on ThreadLocal and hopefully be able to sort out the issue.